# Hide checkbox with label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two divs, First div works as Level 1, Second div work as Level 2.

When I click on checkbox from div LEVEL1. In DIV Level 2, I have checkbox as well as Hyperlink("data-markeralllevel2").

Now based ID of checkbox from LEVEL1 DIV want to Show OR Hide HYPERLINK from DIV Level2.

Example

Level 1                                      Level2
**14** NewText                                          15 NewNo **(14)**

**Checkbox** in LEVEL 2 DIV Hide OR show **working FINE. But** how i can HIDE OR SHOW Hyperlink.

Here is my jquery code.

```js
$("#sectionlistNew").on('click', '.chkremCFAllLevel1HP', function() {
  alert("HIHHHHH");
  marker_ref = $(this).attr('data-markerAllLevel1');
  console.log("Hello 1" + marker_ref);
  $("input[name=chkRolesALLLevel2]").each(function() {
    test_level = $(this).attr("data-markerCheckBoxAllLevel2");
    console.log("Hello2" + test_level);
    if ($(this).attr("data-markerCheckBoxAllLevel2") == marker_ref) {
      console.log("MATCH");
      console.log($(this).attr("data-markerCheckBoxAllLevel2"));
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }

  });
  console.log(marker_ref);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sectionlistNew">
  <input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="14" value="wer" name="chkRolesALLLevel1" chk-marker="NewText">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chkremCFAllLevel1HP" data-markeralllevel1="14"> NewText </a>

  <input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="19" value="2020-03-09" name="chkRolesALLLevel1" chk-marker="NewD">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chkremCFAllLevel1HP" data-markeralllevel1="19"> NewD</a>

  <input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="22" value="2020-03-11" name="chkRolesALLLevel1" chk-marker="NNDate">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chkremCFAllLevel1HP" data-markeralllevel1="22"> NNDate</a>

</div>
<div id="sectionlistLevel2New">
  <input type="checkbox" class="level-one" value="12" name="chkRolesALLLevel2" id="15" chk-marker="NewNo" data-markercheckboxalllevel2="14">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chkremCFAllLevel2HP" data-markeralllevel2="14">NewNo</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a [mcve] with relevant CSS

Comment: @mplungjan ok sir. Thanks for helping me and give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css for resolve such case, or still use jQ to manipulate visibility, just use relevant selectors. 
E.g. `.hiddenClass + a` - mean: next `a` just after block that have class name `hiddenClass`.

```js
$("#sectionlistNew").on('click', '.chkremCFAllLevel1HP', function() {
  alert("HIHHHHH");
  marker_ref = $(this).attr('data-markerAllLevel1');
  console.log("Hello 1" + marker_ref);
  $("input[name=chkRolesALLLevel2]").each(function() {
    test_level = $(this).attr("data-markerCheckBoxAllLevel2");
    console.log("Hello2" + test_level);
    var matched = $(this).attr("data-markerCheckBoxAllLevel2") == marker_ref;

    /* Take attention: `!matched` */

    $(this).toggleClass('hiddenClass', !matched); 
  });
  console.log(marker_ref);
});
```

```css
.hiddenClass {
    display: none;
}

.hiddenClass + a {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sectionlistNew">
  <input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="14" value="wer" name="chkRolesALLLevel1" chk-marker="NewText">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chkremCFAllLevel1HP" data-markeralllevel1="14"> NewText </a>

  <input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="19" value="2020-03-09" name="chkRolesALLLevel1" chk-marker="NewD">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chkremCFAllLevel1HP" data-markeralllevel1="19"> NewD</a>

  <input type="checkbox" class="level-one" id="22" value="2020-03-11" name="chkRolesALLLevel1" chk-marker="NNDate">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chkremCFAllLevel1HP" data-markeralllevel1="22"> NNDate</a>

</div>
<div id="sectionlistLevel2New">
  <input type="checkbox" class="level-one" value="12" name="chkRolesALLLevel2" id="15" chk-marker="NewNo" data-markercheckboxalllevel2="14">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="chkremCFAllLevel2HP" data-markeralllevel2="14">NewNo</a>
</div>
```